# Layout adjustments of Multilingual website

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net

Can anyone guide me about the best practice for designing the layout for multilingual page?

The problem I'm facing is that one word has different characters and length in different languages. The webpages work well in English but when language changed to Russian or other language the layout messed up.

As an example below one is in English and it looks ok

[image]

But the Russian version of the page has a messed up layout

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code of the search on a demo please?

Comment: It's not on search.. it's by setting the UICulture. I assume I need to make different versions of CSS for each language but just want to know if there's any best practice

Comment: You can use on css file.  If you use the lang pseudo class.  This is a good place to start. https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang

Comment: you should have different css files for different languages as some languages like Arabic have RTL instead of LTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some search on this and the only way I found is to load the specific .css file based on the language, specially when you have to implement multilingual thing in old website.

So what I did is declared one `Literal` in html like below in the head tag of an html

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="Literal1" />
```

Than in my codebehind on page load I set the literal text to link the specific css file

```
if (base.User.Language.Equals("Portuguese") || base.User.Language.Equals("Indonesian"))
  {
   Literal1.Text = "<link href='css-files/Portuguese.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>";

  }
else
  Literal1.Text = "<link href='css-files/default-english.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>";
```